# Output error showing error 4, while everything is working fine

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an output error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl',
AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Background; DataItem=null;
target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Fill' (type
'Brush')
```

However, everything is alright in terms of path displaying correctly. I get lots of this errors and they are so annoying, yet everything works as expected, here is the xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckboxListDataTemplate">
            <ContentControl Width="30"
                            Height="30"
                            Background="Black"
                            IsTabStop="False">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource CompoundedViewbox}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<Viewbox x:Key="CompoundedViewbox" x:Shared="False">
    <Grid>
        <Path Data="F1 M 28.437,30.470 C 28.187,30.586 27.908,30.644 " Fill="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
        <Path Data="F1 M 24.917,35.717 C Z" Fill="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The viewbox changes the color anytime I change the background inside the content control, yet it shows that output error, that it could not find it.

Any ideas why it happes?

Ps. I cut out most of the path data, as it would be too long.

Kind Regards

Comment: It's probably because initially, when the view is created, there are no `ContentControls` on the view. Therefore your `RelativeSource` binding can't find the `RelativeSource`.

Comment: @MikeEason Hi, thank you for your reply. Is this something that I should be worried about, something that will potentially slow the wpf app? If so, is there anything I can do to get rid of these errors?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not entirely certain whether this will have any effect on the performance of the application. Do you really _need_ a `DataTemplate` for a `ContentControl`? Could you not just place a `ContentControl` element in your View and bind to `{StaticResource CompoundedViewbox}`? Is there any reason why you would need a `DataTemplate` in this scenario?

Comment: @MikeEason The reason is that I use these vectors in many places. I can just go to that one data template and change the colour etc. If I need to, in one place only, instead of going through about 60 views and changing them individually on every view.